# mediastreamsegmenter over UDP vs FFmpeg pipe

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, mediastreamsegmenter

I'm trying to pipe FFMpeg output into mediastreamsegmenter to create HLS.

However this procedure:

```
Ffmpeg -i {file} <other arguments> -f mpegts | mediastreamsegmenter <arguments>
```

Makes the segmenter create an index for a VOD using the output of FFmpeg rather than a live event. Re-executing this instruction would override the manifest file for every output of ffmpeg.

Is there any way I could have a live ffmpeg pipe to mediastreamsegmenter? I don't want to use UDP as it doesn't make sense here. Video fragments are all local.

Comment: Why don't you output live HLS from FFmpeg directly?

Comment: Mediastreamsegmentor can take care of playlist file and index files of all different bitrate streams and deleting expired fragments

Comment: Can you post the exact commands? For eg. the `ffmpeg` command should use the  `-re` option to read the input at the native frame rate and is also missing the output `-` for stdout.